# SQL query to JPA specification

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa

I have this simplified JPA entities

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    private String name;

    //getters, setters
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "averages")
public class Averages {
    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "student_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Student student;

    private float value;

    //getters, setters
}
```

How I can write this query using JPA Specification and CriteriaBuilder?

```
SELECT students.id
FROM students,
     averages
WHERE averages.student_id = students.id
GROUP BY students.id
HAVING AVG(averages.value) > 6
```

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92 (28 years ago).

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
select student.id 
from Averages average
join average.student student
group by student.id
having avg(average.value)>6
```

i have no way of testing this

Edit: this is using EntityManager#createQuery(String)

Comment: Thank you, but I need a Predicate as result

Comment: @user1649682 Could you please explain what exactly you want to have as results? The list of `student.id` or something also?